# Dynamic Object - How to tell if a property is defined?

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have a dynamic object that looks as follows:

```
this.ChartDetails.Chart
```

'Chart' is dynamic. I want to see if a dynamic property exists on Chart named LeftYAxis. What is the best way to do this on dynamic objects?

I don't think this is a duplicate of [How to detect if a property exists on an ExpandoObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839598/how-to-detect-if-a-property-exists-on-a-dynamic-object-in-c) because it doesn't discuss the best method to do this for dynamic objects.

Comment: if this.ChartDetails.Chart.LeftYAxis != null

Comment: Is this is *your* implementation of DynamicObject ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to detect if a property exists on a dynamic object in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839598/how-to-detect-if-a-property-exists-on-a-dynamic-object-in-c)

Comment: @JohnGathogo - That does not work. An exception will get thrown because when the object does not exist.

Comment: I tried the method posted by @JohnGathogo and it worked fine. Under what circumstances does it cause an exception to be thrown?

Comment: possible duplicate of [dynamic, How to test if a property is available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998954/dynamic-how-to-test-if-a-property-is-available)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
bool isDefined = false;
object axis = null;
try
{
    axis = this.ChartDetails.Chart.LeftYAxis;
    isDefined = true;
}
catch(RuntimeBinderException)
{ }
```

This is what happens at runtime in the first place. (When you access a property the 'dynamic' piece of things only happens when a first-chance exception gets handled by the object's override of `DynamicObject`'s `TryGetMember` and `TrySetMember`

Some objects (like `ExpandoObject`) are actually dictionaries under the hood and you can check them directly as follows:

```
bool isDefined = ((IDictionary<string, object>)this.ChartDetails.Chart)
    .ContainsKey("LeftYAxis");
```

Basically: without knowing what *actual* type `ChartDetails.Chart` is (if it's an `ExpandoObject` a plain ol' subclass of `object` or a subclass of `DynamicObject`) there's no way besides the try/catch above.  If you wrote the code for `ChartDetails` and `Chart` or have access to the source code you can determine what methods exist for the object and use those to check.

Answer (score 7):

For a variety of reasons it's best to avoid try/catch blocks for control flow. Therefore, while Christopher's method attains the desired result, I find this preferable:

```
this.ChartDetails.Chart.GetType().GetProperty("LeftYAxis") != null;
```

Answer (score 1):

This Works if the dynamic object is a json/open-standard format.

I made two different method helpers one for open-standard format and one for "standard object".

```
    // Checks if object typed json or xml has a specific property
    public static bool IsPropertyExistsOpenStandardFormat(dynamic dynamicObject, string propertyName)
    {
        try
        {
            var x = dynamicObject[propertyName];
            if (x != null)
                return true;
        }
        catch 
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    // Checks if standard object has a specific property
    public static bool IsPropertyExistsStandard(dynamic dynamicObject, string propertyName)
    {
        return dynamicObject.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName) != null;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This one is working -:

```
public static bool IsPropertyExists(dynamic dynamicObj, string property)
       {
           try
           {
               var value=dynamicObj[property].Value;
               return true;
           }
           catch (RuntimeBinderException)
           {

               return false;
           }

       }
```