# Ignore Json data when property is missing

Tags: json, foreach

I tried to get the id Field

```
dynamic post = fb.Get("/" + radListControl2.SelectedItem + "/feed?fields=message");

int count = (int)post.data.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    radListControl1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(post.data[i].id));
}
```

It work and return this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "5xxx269_10151xxx50270", 
      "created_time": "2013-05-24T12:52:24+0000"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "5xxx69_101515xxxx270", 
      "created_time": "2013-05-21T19:57:57+0000"
    }, 
    {
      "message": "xxxxx", 
      "id": "xxx_1015157xxx270", 
      "created_time": "2013-05-21T19:44:07+0000"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "xxx", 
      "created_time": "2013-05-21T19:28:32+0000"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "5xx69_1015xxx75270", 
      "created_time": "2013-05-19T22:02:24+0000"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "52xxx269_1xxxx40270", 
      "created_time": "2013-05-18T09:31:42+0000"
    }, 
    {
      "message": "xxxx", 
      "id": "xxxx", 
      "created_time": "2013-05-17T22:59:49+0000"
    },
```

id xxx is inserted in radlistbox, but this code returns the same list

```
int count = (int)post.data.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    radListControl1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(post.data[i].message));
}
```

but radlistbox is empty, i need only field Message can you help me please?

Comment: The question title is about `foreach` loops but the question body is about `for` loops. Which is it?

Comment: Is an exception thrown when you try to get `message` but none exists?

Comment: Only two of your entries have a `message` field. Is it choking on that? You might want to [test for the existence of the property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998954/dynamic-how-to-test-if-a-property-is-available) before trying to use it.

Comment: It can take the message field only when there is?

Comment: Misleading title contributes negative value to this site. Future visitors with the same problem will not be able to find this question, and people with questions about foreach will get this question in their search results even though it is of no use to them.

Comment: sorry, title corrected by chris =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps only add when there is a value...

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    string message = post.data[i].message;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message)) 
        continue;

    radListControl1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(message));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hasOwnProperty` to check for the existence of a property on an object

```
if (post.data[i].hasOwnProperty("message") {
    radListControl1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(post.data[i].message));
}
```