# Raw results from ServiceStack.OrmLite query

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm wondering if there's a way to get "raw" results from a OrmLite query in ServiceStack.

I'll explain... I know I can use:

```
var results = Db.SqlList<MyModel>("SELECT * FROM TableName");
```

passing the model of my output results, but if I don't know it?
Can I get "raw" results without know the types of the data I'm reading?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the support of [Dynamic Result sets in OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#dynamic-result-sets).

Where you can access an un-typed schema with a `List<object>`, e.g:

```
var results = Db.SqlList<List<object>>("SELECT * FROM TableName");
```

Or if you want the column names as well you can use:

```
var results = db.Select<Dictionary<string,object>>("SELECT * ...");
```

OrmLite also has a version of Dapper embedded if you prefer to access the results using `dynamic` instead, e.g:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> results = db.Query("SELECT * FROM TableName");
```

Comment: @wizzy I've no idea what you mean, can you update your question and spell out exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems to solve my problem!
Is there a way to map NULL values returned from the query?
Dynamic Result returns something like: "__type": "System.DBNull, mscorlib"; while Dapper returns nothing at all.

Comment: @wizzy still not clear on what you're asking, if you're talking about inspecting nulls with dynamic have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5768449/85785 otherwise you'll have to ask a new question.