# Manipulating JSON String in C# without Object

Tags: c#, json, appendchild

I have JSON String which I am reading from file.
I don't have the source of the JSON Object.
So I can't call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`.

However I want check if the JSON String has specific structure, if yes, append some string or If not append the structure.

```
allmodules {
    feature: 'test-a'
}

submodules {
    //some data
}
```

Assume if there's not `allmodules`, I would like to append my structure

```
allmodules {
    feature: 'debug-a'
}
```

If it's already available, just append `feature: 'debug-a'`

And so on I have some custom work to do. Is there any efficient way to do this without breaking JSON format. Most of the questions regarding String to Object de-serialization, however as I mentioned I don't have original Object, and can't do that.

Comment: *I don't have the source of the JSON Object.* Then where is the JSON?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov JSON is coming from file. Think of like a tool to tune/append some data to JSON file at runtime

Comment: So input is any json and the output is a json that confirms to your json schema.

Comment: @singsuyash, output json which complies with source json structure. however I am appending some text which will not break the structure

Comment: Does the JSON have a known structure? Or will they be completely dynamic?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, it has. however my tool shouldn't be checking against that. Think it like this, I am adding some JSON string which is compatible with source structure.

Comment: you want this json, just to test your functionality right?

Comment: @singsuyash, It's a tool to append some json string to source

Comment: @Reddy so you pretty much want to deserialize the JSON to a dynamic object and test if some properties are valid? [perhaps with a try/catch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998954/test-if-a-property-is-available-on-a-dynamic-variable) or even reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `JObject` and doing a little manual parsing. It could look something like this:

```
public string AppendAllModules(string json)
{
    var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
    JToken token;
    if (obj.TryGetValue("allmodules", out token))
        return json;

    obj.Add(new JProperty("allmodules", new JObject(new JProperty("feature", "test-a"))));
    return obj.ToString();
}
```

Given:

```
{
    "submodules": {
        "name": "yuval"
    }
}
```

Would yield:

```
{
  "submodules": {
    "name": "yuval"
  },
  "allmodules": {
    "feature": "test-a"
  }
}
```

Comment: @singsuyash Your code doesn't meet the requirements of the OP. You simply append a new key value pair. I started writing this answer before you posted yours :)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't have the source of the JSON Object.

No worries, you can simply construct a new C# object that it compatible with the JSON definition.  There are a number of options listed at

[How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON object string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611674/how-to-auto-generate-a-c-sharp-class-file-from-a-json-object-string)

Once you have a compatible C# class in your project, you can deserialize the JSON and manipulate it as an object, just as if you had the original object.

Comment: J, what if the source JSON string changes. I don't have specific model that JSON will be like this. it might have some child attributes or may not be. The point is I don't have to understand the entire JSON of the same, just to go with append my customization and move on

Comment: @Reddy: If you deserialize to a type, type safety will protect you from incompatible changes that you may be ignorant to if you simply manipulate the JSON as a string.  My preference would be to have my code break if a third-party dependency changes unexpectedly, rather than blindly processing that dependency.

Comment: I do agree with you however I don't have rights to import (call it as restriction)

Answer (score 0):

use either `JObject.FromObject` or `JObject.Parse` to get your file json string into a `JObject`. 
Then the below example code may help. I am going via an `If/else` way because you mentioned you can not get the exact structure.

```
JObject obj = JObject.FromObject(
        new {Id = 5, Name = "Foo"}
    );
    JToken jtok = null;
    bool found = obj.TryGetValue("Bar",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase, out jtok);
    if (!found)
    {
        obj.Add("Bar","this is added");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(jtok);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(obj["Bar"]);
```

Of course after you are done editing your `JObject` you can  use the `JObject.ToString()` method to get the string representation and send it over to the file.