# dynamic type does not contain a definition for 'property', error?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I m trying to check if a dynamic type has a property by comparing it to null  but code throws the following error:

> 'GT_Type' does not contain a definition for 'GT_eligible'

Below is my code:

```
     if (GT_Type.GT_eligible == null)
            {
//do something
};
```

Kindly guide how I can check if a property exists in dynamic type ?

Comment: You can breakpoint it in Visual Studio and hover over `GT_Type`.  Visual Studio will tell you its available public members.  However, if you're getting that error, you can be pretty sure that `GT_Type` does not contain a member called `GT_eligible`.  Have you checked your casing?  I would expect the name of that member (based on your naming conventions) to be `GT_Eligible` (notice the capital E?).

Comment: thanks @RobertHarvey, question is how I can avoid this error ? I want to check if this property exist or not. It is dynamic type so sometime this property may be in object and sometime now.

Comment: Catch the resulting exception, or use reflection.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998954/test-if-a-property-is-available-on-a-dynamic-variable  You can also try something like [TryGetMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetmember(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks, and sorry if it is not allowed but I m curies why checking (comparing) with null do not work in this scenario ?