# Accesing a Class.Name property from diffrent classes without inheritance

Tags: c#, generic-programming

I am trying to write a Method that uses the `Name` property of diffrent classes and does some logic with it.

In my exampel to keep it simple i will restrict myself to simply returning the `Name` value:

```
class Dog
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Human
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

/*
 ...
*/

public string GetNameFromNameProperty(object obj)
{
    return obj.Name;
}
```

Sadly the classes are not inherting from a parent class that has the `Name` property. Furthermore it is not possible to implement that or add an interface.

---

Short Recap:
Is it possible to write a generic Method that uses a `Name` property without being sure that the class has implemented that property?

---

Comment: You should use an `interface` in which you defines the `Name` property.

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998954/test-if-a-property-is-available-on-a-dynamic-variable an option?

Comment: No its not possible in C# without `dynamic` or Reflection, but a base class or interface is the more idiomatic, type-safe approach.

Comment: But then i would have to implement the interfaces in all the classes that i wish to pass, e,g. in `Dog` and `Human`. If i am not mistaken it would be the same result as inheriting from a base class.

Comment: maybe you need reflection for this

Comment: So you mean you have lots of these classes and it's very hard to make them all implement an interface?

Comment: Dynamic did the trick

Comment: What do you want to happen if `obj` does not have a `string Name` property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test if a property is available on a dynamic variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998954/test-if-a-property-is-available-on-a-dynamic-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* don't want to make all those classes implement a common interface or inherit from a base class, then here are two options:

Reflection:

```
public string GetNameFromNameProperty(object obj)
{
    var type = obj.GetType();
    return type.GetProperty("Name").GetValue(obj) as string;
}
```

Dynamic Binding:

```
public string GetNameFromNameProperty(dynamic obj)
{
    try
    {
        return obj.Name;
    }
    catch (RuntimeBinderException)
    {
        throw new PropertyDoesntExistException();
    }
}
```

You can also choose to return null if the property does not exist.

However, I strongly advise you to use interfaces or inheritance to do this. You basically lose all the type-safety that C# provides if you used the above methods.

Comment: You answer is much higher quality than the one i compose. I still want to thank [mjwills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34092/mjwills) who directed me to the right answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5768449/5757162) bevor you answerd it :)