# Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' does not contain a definition for 'result'

Tags: c#, rest, api

I am trying to read Rest API, everything works fine and I am getting data back from api but it is failing on line where it says if (response.Data.result == null). I am getting an error saying 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' does not contain a definition for 'result'. Any help will be highly appreciated. Here is the code:

```
        try
        {
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
            {
                var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader _answer = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                string result = _answer.ReadToEnd();
                var responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);



                if (responseData.result == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(responseData.result.ToString()))                    
                    return null;
                else
                {
                    var contactData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Contact>(responseData.result.ToString());
                    return contactData;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are deserialising to `dynamic` rather than a concrete type?

Comment: mjwills, 
I inherited this code and trying to make it work...I am open to any other solutions...

Comment: If you're stuck using the `dynamic` type then this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998954/test-if-a-property-is-available-on-a-dynamic-variable - otherwise look to use concrete types as suggested

Comment: I assume you mean "it is failing on line where it says if (responseData.result == null)" - your original refers to `response.Data.result` (note the extra `.`). I don't want to edit it myself in case my assumption is wrong!

Comment: Chris, Yes, I meant to say responseData. result

Answer (score 0):

You can check directly if the parsed object is `null` or not:

```
if (responseData == null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(responseData.ToString()))       
                return null;
```

Comment: Bassel, with your response, I think I have figured it out, I removed the work result and used the following line which resolved the issue
responseData[0] == null

I will do some more testing to see if it breaks at any point...thanks

Comment: I am getting this error now.... Error converting value \"8724c022-1276-4a58-9efe-1c566a925552\" to type 'System.Int64'. Path 'UserUid'

Comment: you're converting a non-integer string to integer, `UserUid` should string not int @Mr_Roomi